# Ruby on Rails caching with memcache and Dalli doesn't seem to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached, dalli

so I implemented some caching on my page that runs on rails 3.3 but when I look into the production log I see this:

```
Read fragment views/#<Job:0xbbb6970>_big_2 (0.8ms)
Write fragment views/#<Job:0xbbb6970>_big_2 (0.5ms)
Read fragment views/#<Job:0xbbb65d8>_big_2 (0.5ms)
Write fragment views/#<Job:0xbbb65d8>_big_2 (0.6ms)
Read fragment views/#<Job:0xbbb61b4>_big_2 (0.6ms)
Write fragment views/#<Job:0xbbb61b4>_big_2 (0.4ms)
Rendered shared/_jobslist.html.erb (88.5ms)
```

I am not sure this is supposed to be like this :) As far as I understand it, it should read all the time once the fragment is saved in cache. I specified an expiration of 30 minutes.

```
<% jobs.each_with_index do |job, i| %>                                         
    <% cache("#{job}_big_2", :expires => 30.minutes) do %>
       ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your cache key is the problem (the first argument to `#cache`). You're telling Rails to identify the cached fragments using the string `"#{job}_big_2"`. To interpolate a `Job` instance into that string, Ruby will call `#to_s` on it, resulting in the `#<Job:0xbbb61b4>` segments you see. But this contains the object_id, which will be different each time the record is loaded - this is why you're not getting any cache hits.

If `Job` is a descendant of `ActiveRecord::Base`, you can use the `#cache_key` method, which will produce a string with the record's record ID and `updated_at` timestamp to produce a key that is unique to that record, but which will be regenerated if the record is updated:

```
<% jobs.each_with_index do |job, i| %>                                         
    <% cache("#{job.cache_key}_big_2", :expires => 30.minutes) do %>
       ...

Read fragment views/jobs/1234-20130614084704_big_2 (0.8ms)
...
```

If `Job` is not an `AR::Base` model then you need to implement a similar method to generate a cache key that will uniquely identify your `Job` records.